# what makes an OWL class anonymous?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

I am reading a tutorial that says that this is an anonymous OWL class:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Reptile"> 
       <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Animal”/> 
       <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#OxygenUser”/> 
</owl :Class>
```

I know what an anonymous class is in Java. What makes this class anonymous in OWL? Is it anonymous because it does not have an RDFS:label statement like this: `<rdfs:label>Reptile</rdfs:label>` ?

Answer (score 3):

OWL anonymous classes are classes without a name/identifier (URI). Usually it's an OWL class expression such as `eats some Grass` or `Male and Female`. You use such expression in combination with named classes to create axioms.

Example of equivalent classes axioms using both named an anonymous classes (comments are shown by the `#` symbol):

```
# Named class (got a dereferencable URI)
Class: <http://www.example.org/Man>

# Named Class
Class: <http://www.example.org/Woman>

# Named class
Class: <http://www.example.org/Human>

    # The named class Human is equivalent 
    # to the anonymous class (class expression) Man or Woman
    EquivalentTo: <http://www.example.org/Man> or <http://www.example.org/Woman>
```

Comment: so the classes Man and Woman are only anonymous when they are part of an axiom? also, even in an axiom, don't they have deferencable URIs (ie the URIs in the equivalentTo statement)? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: The whole expression `Man or Woman` is an anonymous class, it's built by composing with the named classes `Woman` and `Man` and by using the `or` constructor. This expression refers to the set of things that are either a man or a woman, yet doesn't give a name to it (anonymous class). You can then use expression to build axioms as shown is the example. `Man` and `Woman` are always named classes here, any expression built combining these results in an anonymous class.

Comment: Just saw your example, I'm not sure I clearly see any anonymous class. I would say that `OxygenUser` and `Animal` are named classes, then the anonymous class would be `OxygenUser and Animal` which finally gives the axiom `Reptile` subClassOf `OxygenUser and Animal`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a source URL for the tutorial? The example you quote does not contain any anonymous classes, so if that's a direct quote from the tutorial, it's giving out wrong information.